# String character identity paradox

Tags: python, string, python-internals

I'm completely stuck with this

```
>>> s = chr(8263)
>>> x = s[0]
>>> x is s[0]
False
```

How is this possible? Does this mean that accessing a string character by indexing create a new instance of the same character? Let's experiment:

```
>>> L = [s[0] for _ in range(1000)]
>>> len(set(L))
1
>>> ids = map(id, L)
>>> len(set(ids))
1000
>>>
```

Yikes what a waste of bytes ;) Or does it mean that `str.__getitem__` has a hidden feature? Can somebody explain?

But this is not the end of my surprise:

```
>>> s = chr(8263)
>>> t = s
>>> print(t is s, id(t) == id(s))
True True
```

This is clear: `t` is an alias for `s`, so they represent the same object and identities coincide. But again, how the following is possible:

```
>>> print(t[0] is s[0])
False
```

`s` and `t` are the same object so what?

But worse:

```
>>> print(id(t[0]) == id(s[0]))
True
```

`t[0]` and `s[0]` have not been garbage collected, are considered as the same object by the `is` operator but have different ids? Can somebody explain?

Comment: Your char is actually a single-element string, so yes, accessing char by index creates new string of length 1.

Comment: I get this- `ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)` when i run this- `s=chr(8263)`

Comment: how does the duplicate explain `t[0] is s[0] -> False` even if `id(t[0]) == id(s[0]) -> True`?

Comment: @CrakC Probably because you are using Python 2. the `unichr` standard function will do the job.

Comment: @P.Ortiz That's right! How is the behaviour different in Python 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two points to make here.

First, Python does indeed create a *new* character with the `__getitem__` call, but only if that character has ordinal value *greater* than 256.

For example:

```
>>> s = chr(256)
>>> s[0] is s
True

>>> t = chr(257)
>>> t[0] is t
False
```

This is because internally, the compiled [`getitem`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8f48717b74e/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l10987) function checks the ordinal value of the single chracter and calls the [`get_latin1_char`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8f48717b74e/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l1725) if that value is 256 or less. This allows some single-character strings to be shared. Otherwise, a new unicode object is created.

The second issue concerns garbage collection and shows that the interpreter can reuse memory addresses very quickly. When you write:

```
>>> s = t # = chr(257)
>>> t[0] is s[0]
False
```

Python first creates two new single character strings and then compares their memory addresses. These have different addresses (we have different objects as per the explanation above) so comparing the objects with `is` returns False.

On the other hand, we can have the seemingly paradoxical situation that:

```
>>> id(t[0]) == id(s[0])
True
```

But this is because the interpreter quickly reuses the memory address of `t[0]` when it creates the new string `s[0]` at a later moment in time.

If you examine the bytecode this line produces (e.g. with `dis` - see below), you see that the addresses for each side are allocated one after the other (a new string object is created and then `id` is called on it).

The references to the object `t[0]` drop to zero as soon as `id(t[0])` is returned (we're doing the comparison on integers now, not the object itself). This means that `s[0]` can reuse the same memory address when it is created afterwards.

---

Here is the disassembled bytecode for the line `id(t[0]) == id(s[0])` which I've annotated.

You can see that the lifetime of `t[0]` ends before `s[0]` is created (there are no references to it) hence its memory can be reused.

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (id)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (t)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR                     # t[0] is created
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1        # id(t[0]) is computed...
                                                  # ...lifetime of string t[0] over
             13 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (id)
             16 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (s)
             19 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             22 BINARY_SUBSCR                     # s[0] is created...
                                                  # ...free to reuse t[0] memory
             23 CALL_FUNCTION            1        # id(s[0]) is computed
             26 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)   # the two ids are compared
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Thanks for you informative and convicing response. But it raises one question: doesn't it contradict the immutability of strings? By definition, immutability of a string `s` means that the  `s[valid_index]` object never changes during the string life time?

Comment: @P.Ortiz: no problem, glad it helped. If I understood you correctly, then this doesn't contradict the immutability of string objects as far as I can see. For the first part, it seems that `s[i]` just checks whether the i-th character of `s` is in the 0-256 range and, if it is, returns the singleton string object given by `chr(i)`. For the comparing `id` part, the lifetime of `t[0]` is over as far as Python is concerned and so `s[0]` is free to occupy the memory it was in. No string objects are mutated.

Comment: I try to to be clearer: the Python Ref. docs explains: "when we talk about the mutability of a container, only the *identities* of the immediately contained objects are implied." So now, suppose you have the following string: `s=chr(8263)`. If you perform indexing on `s`, for instance an innocent assignment as `x=s[0]`, *identity* of of the first item in `s` has *changed* (`str.getitem` returns a new value as explained in your response). What I mean is that `str.__getitem__` is a mutating method (string state has been altered). But, an immutable object doesn't have any mutating methods.

Comment: Writing `x = s[0]` doesn't mutate or alter `s` at all. If `s` is just the single character given by `chr(8263)` then `x = s[0]` creates a new string object in memory and assigns the name `x` to it. So now `s[0]` is a representation of the same unicode character as `s`, but it exists at new address in memory (it has a different identity). The string object `s` has not been changed in any way.

Comment: Indeed, as you said : *it has a different identity* and that's the problem for  me (recall what Python docs explains :  "when we talk about the mutability of a container, only the **identities** of the immediately contained objects are implied" (emphasis is mine).

Comment: That quote is certainly true but makes more sense for containers like tuples, rather than strings.  Tuples themselves are immutable but might contain mutable objects such as lists; you can change the list that the tuple contains. Strings are also immutable not containers in this same sense; they do not contain other Python objects. `s[0]` is not returning a character contained `s`, it is looking at the first byte (in the case of UTF-8) of `s` and creating a whole new string object that is equal to it.

Answer (score 0):

`is` compare identities and `==` compare values. Check this [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)

> Every object has an identity, a type and a value. An object’s identity
>   never changes once it has been created; you may think of it as the
>   object’s address in memory. The ‘is‘ operator compares the identity of
>   two objects; the id() function returns an integer representing its
>   identity (currently implemented as its address). An object’s type is
>   also unchangeable.